# How to duplicate report in Crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having a Report for receipts where needs to be duplicated at the bottom,

- If there 6 records for report, 3 records should be shown in the first page top and duplication of that 3 records will be shown in page bottom
- From Record 4 to 6 will be shown in next page, where as same records has to be duplicated in bottom of second page.

I have created a sub report from original report and linked.

01.I Checked "Select data un subreport based on field"

Since its at the page footer, it only pass last record of page where i need all 3 records. apart from that paging works correctly.

Please refer following screenshot of first 2 pages.

[image]

Full Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Z2J.png

02.I unchecked  "Select data un subreport based on field", but it shows same 3 records in each page in sub report

[image]

Full Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l7HA.png

Comment: now what is the issue?

Comment: If you consider first screen shot, i want to have same 3 records in each pageat the bottom where as i am getting only last record.

Comment: but in second screenshot you have 3 records. right?

Comment: there are 3 records, but if you check 2 nd page sub report at the bottom, you can see its STD001, STD002, STD003 where as i want to have STD004, STD005, STD006 in seconds page

Comment: solution would be use the same report as the sub report and don't link  main report and sub report. Have you tried this way?

Comment: I did without linking, its also same as screenshot 2 where same 3 records have been repeated over pages. In that case if it changes page of sub report when main report page changes, then it would work

Comment: Where did you place the records in main report? I mean in which section?

Comment: I have placed sub report in the footer.

Comment: Place the records in detail section in main report and link the sub report and in sub report also place the records in detail section

Comment: Yeah records are in details in both main report and sub report
and sub report is placed at footer, this is my crystal report
http://www.mediafire.com/download/icw1kh8n6t2e5ba/11.rpt

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion would be don't place sub report in report footer but instead place in page footer. If this doesn't work then follow below process.

If your requirement is only 3 records then I would suggest not to go with sub report instead you can follow below process.

```
1. Place 3 rows in page footer.
2. From detail section store all rows as arrays in variables.
3. Now extract the values from variables page to page and display those in page footer
```

To store in array follow below process:
1. Create a formula and write below code.. I am giving for on column extend it for other columns aswell.

```
Shared String VarArray abc;

Abc=abc+Student number <<This is the student number field coming from database>>
```

Place above formula beside student column in detail section

Now to go to page footer.
In first formula write below code.

```
Share String VarArray abc;
abc[1];
```

similar way writer for other formulas aswell

reset the `abc` at the end of all formulas.

Comment: Thank you actually i added sub report in page footer and tried it was same.

For you second scenario, how can i store and extract values, is there any formula for that? Sorry I don't have thorough knowledge about crystal formulas

Comment: Thanks for Help i did it in another way i will post the answer